# Continue with the conversation flow in Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

Is it possible to continue with the conversation flow after a user input does not fit to a condition? In this example I want to continue with the conversation flow - but the conversation jumps to the root.

Example Conversation:
[image]
I tried "Continue from ..." but it only works if I go back one step. This repeats the question. Is there a way to avoid the second question in the conversation?

Example Conversation with Continue from:
[image]

Comment: Set your continue from to the "Wait for User Input" node just before the "@YesNo:Yes" node.

Comment: Thank you! That works! I didn't realized that I can click on the callout symbol if I insert a "Continue from"